# After printing the previous line where the file contains a single token now need to traverse through the result to meet the requirement

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have used the below code to print the previous line where the file contains a single token

```
#! /bin/ksh

file=input.txt
while read line
do
awk 'NF == 1 { print LAST } { LAST=$0 }'
done < "$file"
```

Now I need to traverse through the result and need to check 9th position, 11th, 13th, etc. till the end of the line with the consecutive odd positions and if those positions are not matching with any of the mentioned numerics:

```
201 
230 
197 
193 
229 
200 
215 
226 
001 
198
```

It should print the error as `CORRUPTED`, if not `AVAILABLE` should be printed.

Here is the example of my file :

```
59 6 18 2014 169 7 14 2 7671912 7849744 201 4
60 6 19 2014 170 5 49 2 7671912 7849744 201 5
61 6 20 2014 171 6 8 2 7671912 7849744 201 6
62 6 23 2014 174 5 3 2 7671912 7849744 201 7
63 6 23 2014 174 7 17 2 7671912 7849744 201 8
64 6 24 2014 175 16 13 2 7671912 7849744 201 9
65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 7671912 7849744 201 10
10
1 1 49 6 16 2014 7 39 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 2 49 6 17 2014 13 15 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 3 49 6 18 2014 1 38 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 4 49 6 18 2014 7 14 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
1 5 49 6 19 2014 5 49 201 1 0 1043 <au_launchpad_back.gif> 201 gif <SIZE> 871
```

If we consider this as example 9th position is 7671912

NOTE : The code should be feasible at any other file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 7671912 7849744 201 10" |
awk 'FNR == NR { a[$1]; next }
     {
         for (i = 9; i <= NF; i += 2) {
             if (!($i in a)) {
                 flag = 1;
             }
          }
          if (flag) {
              print "CORRUPTED";                  
          } else {
              print "AVAILABLE";                  
          }
     }
' file -
CORRUPTED
```

`file` contains all your numerics to compare. You must replace `echo "65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 7671912 7849744 201 10"` from this test by script which print previous line where the file contains a single token.

**Explanation**

- `FNR == NR { a[$1]; next }`: while processing `file`, we save each number in `file` to an array `a`.
- After reading `file`, we loop through all odd fields, starting at field `9th`, if field value not in array `a`, we set `flag = 1`.
- Finally, if `flag` is set to 1, meaning we have at least one field that its value not in `file`, so we print `CORRUPTED`, otherwise print `AVAiLABLE`.

Comment: can you please explain the code how it works, so that i can try to modify @gnouc

Comment: can you please pause the URL where you have updated

Comment: im totally getting confused, could you please pass the correct code in any pastebin and share the link please @gnouc

Comment: im really sorry, im unable to view can you please post the code now in any fresh pastebin and share the link @gnouc

Comment: if my code is i=8 then for 65 6 25 2014 176 8 20 2 201 10 230 10 226 10 its printing "AVAILABLE", if i pass any junk value in place of 226 with 222126, it should display CORRUPTED since its not matching with num.txt value. But im facing the problem as AVAILABLE. :( @gnouc

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dpif8kqJ please check @gnouc

Comment: See my updated. It seems that you don't try your self reading the code? It's a simple mistyping.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/81q0DnvM I made few changes and now it works, thanks a lot for the help and your time :) @gnouc